# In a normal workflow, lighting is to be done first or shading?

Tags: workflow

After modeling and uv unwrapping, should I continue with shading or should I start setting up lights first?

I've seen professionals doing both and sometimes doing them together. What are the benefits of each workflow? Is it different based on the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is actually opinion based.

But from a purely technical point of view, the following fact arises:
The light from a light source is reflected from surfaces to a certain extent (frequency/color, intensity, angle/scattering), and this process is repeated until the energy has been completely absorbed.

This means that the two cannot be considered separately.

But in practice, the following sequence is usually helpful:

- implement rough lighting concept
- define colors and reflective properties of surfaces
- set up light
- refine materials
- optimize light
- repeat the last two steps until your illusion is convincing

...And yes, it always depends on the scene, of course.

Comment: For the OP - PBR materials make this simpler. They'll always behave realistically, so you only adjust the lighting - just like in real world photography :))

Comment: @JachymMichal have you seen the array of products photographers use to adjust real world materials, like dulling sprays? ;)

Comment: @MartyFouts that's a good point and no, I didn't know that :))

Comment: @JachymMichal even most pro photographers don't deal with such things.  You usually only see this stuff if you're doing product photography and then only in cases where you need either more or less reflection from some part of the object than it would 'naturally' have.  Turns out, though, that dulling spray is popular with people doing photogrammetry.

Comment: @MartyFouts Learned more about photography on a blender site than in 3 years in art school :))